# Regex to match number with or without decimal and exclude decimal

Tags: regex

So I have a regular expression pattern like: `^([\d]+)(\.[\d]{1,2}?)$`

I need it to match numbers like `10001`, `10001.1` and `10001.10`, ignoring numbers formatted in such a way like: `1000a`, `10001.` and `10001.100`.

This expression seems to work well and gives me the two parts, but how do I make it exclude the decimal point?

Right now if I give it `10001.10` I will get two parts: `10001` and `.10` is there a way to make it so it gives me `10001` and `10`?

Comment: @Unihedron, I had tried: _^(\d+)(?:\.)(\d{1,2})?$_ brackets in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?$
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lC9dS2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below regex,

```
^([\d]+)(?:\.([\d]{1,2}?))?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kF4pU2/5)

Comment: What is the need of `[\d]`, it can be just `\d`

Comment: @anubhava sure. If  i change that, it will look like your's :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
^(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?$
```

Comment: And now this regex becomes copy of my answer :)

Comment: @anubhava you already have too much reputation hahah leave some for the poor

Comment: lol :) no I don't intend to eat out anyone's rep, it was just a comment that exactly similar answer was already there.